# Can i use dataProvider in one package and data receiver i another package and import it in testng

Tags: selenium, testng

My code:

```
@Test(priority = 9, dataProvider = "refno")
public void searchAgain(String reffno) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    String str1 = reffno;
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_txtref']")).sendKeys(str1);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_imgSearch']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_txtref']")).clear();
}
```

Comment: please add a bit of context to your question's code to explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can specify the class name of the [`DataProvider`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) along with its package as:

```
@Test(priority = 9, dataProvider = "refno", dataProviderClass=com.another.package.DataProvider.class)
public void searchAgain(String reffno)
```

which shall generally transform(since the complete package path could be moved to import) as:

```
@Test(priority = 9, dataProvider = "refno", dataProviderClass=DataProvider.class)
public void searchAgain(String reffno)
```

Comment: @ManjunathKotagi Cool. If it helps do mark an answer for future readers to find it useful.